# Objective-C - If statements

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Quick qeustion, my code:

```
if (slider2.value == 1) 
{
    barHeight = 100;
}
else if (slider2.value == 2) 
{
    barHeight = 200;
}
else if (slider2.value == 3) 
{
    barHeight = 300;
}
else if (slider2.value == 4) 
{
    barHeight = 400;
}
else if (slider2.value == 5) 
{
    barHeight = 500;
}
else
{
    barHeight = 600; 
}
```

When I drag the slider from 1 to 6 I see the height of the bar change. But when I move from 6 to 1 the barHeight is stuck at 600 and does not return to 100. What am I missing?

Edit ( full statement ):

```
- (void)valueAgeChanged:(UISlider*)slider2
{
// DRAW BARS (skeme)
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(595, barX, 80, barHeight);
orangeView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:orangeView];

// Let slider 1 animate on set value
[slider2 setValue:((int)((slider2.value + 1) / 1.0) - 1.0) animated:NO];


if (slider2.value == 1) {
    barHeight = 100;
}else if (slider2.value == 2) {
    barHeight = 200;
   // barX = 300;
}else if (slider2.value == 3) {
    barHeight = 300;
}else if (slider2.value == 4) {
    barHeight = 400;
}else if (slider2.value == 5) {
    barHeight = 500;
}else if (slider2.value == 6) {
    barHeight = 600; 
}


}
```

Comment: did you try to rewrite this with switch-case statement?

Comment: The code seems okay, maybe a problem in the surrounding code? When is this statement called?

Comment: Maybe switch() would be better? And don't forger the default()

Comment: This happens on UISlider valueChange? Could you post the rest of the function?

Comment: @freytag : The statement is called in : - (void)valueAgeChanged:(UISlider*)slider2.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint to the code to see, what's happening.

Comment: Oh, forget switch - `barHeight = slider2.value * 100;`

Comment: @Sulthan : has the same effect..height goes up but doesnt go down. (way shorter code tho)

Comment: @Peteee24 : Yea..that wrong?

Comment: I wonder what is `(int)((slider2.value + 1) / 1.0) - 1.0` supposed to do.

Comment: Show the code that applies `barHeight`.

Comment: @Sulthan A slider's value is a float value. That code forces the slider to have only integer values. Though it is pointless to divide by 1.0. That whole line is the same as `floor(slider2.value)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding a new orangeView every time your value is changed. So they are simply overlaying each other. The tallest view will remain on screen and when you add shorter views of the same colour you won't see them.

To fix this you could set up the orangeView property outside of your valueChanged method (maybe viewDidLoad) and add it as a subview.
Then whenever your slider updates only update the frame of your view.

e.g.

```
- (void)valueAgeChanged:(UISlider*)slider2
{

[slider2 setValue:((int)((slider2.value + 1) / 1.0) - 1.0) animated:NO];

if (slider2.value == 1) {
    barHeight = 100;
}else if (slider2.value == 2) {
    barHeight = 200;
   // barX = 300;
}else if (slider2.value == 3) {
    barHeight = 300;
}else if (slider2.value == 4) {
    barHeight = 400;
}else if (slider2.value == 5) {
    barHeight = 500;
}else if (slider2.value == 6) {
    barHeight = 600; 
}

self.orangeView.frame = CGRectMake(595, barX, 80, barHeight);

}
```

You should also move this to after your if else statement, otherwise it will only update with the previous value.

EDIT:
As rmaddy points out the if statement is a bit overkill in this instance. A switch may be more readable/efficient, but as your barHeight is simply the slider value multiplied by 100 it would be much easier to write:

```
- (void)valueAgeChanged:(UISlider*)slider2
{

barHeight = floorf(slider2.value) * 100;
self.orangeView.frame = CGRectMake(595, barX, 80, barHeight);

}
```

Comment: Replace `[slider2 setValue:((int)((slider2.value + 1) / 1.0) - 1.0) animated:NO];` with `slider2.value = floor(slider2.value);`

Comment: Replace the whole `if-else` block with `barHeight = slider2.value * 100;`.

Comment: Yes I would agree with that, but wanted to address the problem in the question about why the bar didn't appear to be changing height. There are definitely optimisations to be made.